# Bijective function proof in $R\times R$ and $Z\times N$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics

How can I verify if these functions are bijective?

$ f_4:\Bbb{R^2} \rightarrow \Bbb{R^2}, \ (x,\ y)\mapsto (x+y,\ x-y)$

$ f_5:\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{N^*} \rightarrow \Bbb Q, \ (p,\ q)\mapsto p + \cfrac{1}{q} \ $

I'm stuck, so any tip will be helpful

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can begin by verifying the definitions of injectivity and surjectivity.

Comment: For the second one, try and see why $\frac34$ is not in the range of $f_5$.

Comment: Finding an inverse would prove a function invertible... and all invertible functions between sets are bijective. Failure to find an inverse might shed light on how to prove a function isn't bijective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x+y, \ x-y) = (x'+y', \ x'-y') \implies x +y = x' + y' \;\;\; \& \;\;\; x - y = x'-y' $$

$$\implies x = y \;\;\; \& \;\;\; x' = y' \implies (x, y) = (x', y')\ \implies f_4 \;\; \text{is injective.}$$

for each $(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \;\; \exists (\frac {x + y} {2}, \frac {x - y} {2}) \in \Bbb R^2 $ such that $f_4(\frac {x + y} {2}, \frac {x - y} {2}) = (x, y) \implies f_4 \;\; \text{is surjective}$.

Therefore $f_4$ is bijective.

As far as $f_5$ is concerned as Asaf Karagalia has pointed out $\frac 3 4 \in R(f_5) \implies (4p - 3)q = -4$ for some $p \in \Bbb Z$ and $ q \in \Bbb N$

Since $q \in \Bbb N $ and $q \ |  \ (-4)$ , $q =1, 2 $or $4 $. Each case would imply that $p$ is not an integer. This implies that $\frac 3 4 \notin R(f_5) $. But since $\frac 3 4$ is a rational number $f_5$ is not surjective and therefore not bijective.